# @Transactional on top of JAX-RS endpoint class

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jta

I came across below code

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Path("/event")
public class EventService {

    @Inject
    private EventInterface emEventService;

    @PUT
    @Path("/send")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional(value=TxType.REQUIRED)
    public Response group(MyObject myObject) {
        OutputObject outputObject = emEventService.groupUpdate(myObject);
        return Response.status(200).entity(outputObject).build();
    }
}
```

1. What is the use of having `@Transactional` annotation on top of the JAX-RS endpoint class ?
2. I have a use case where a list of item are sent in REST call as a JSON input. And either all these items in the list should be updated in the DB or none of them should in case of failure. Can i achieve this with the help of above `@Transactional` annotation on top of my JAX-RS endpoint class ?

eg : For below JSON either update corresponding entry for parentEvent and both the correlatedEvents in DB or in case of failure update none of them.

```
{
"parentEvent": "1",
"correlatedEvents": [
{
"id": "2"
},
{
"id": "3"
}
],
"changeTime" : "2020-10-10T07:04:15.6Z",
"sourceSystemId": "SOURCE"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*disclaimer*: I am not an JPA expert, I simply had various experiences with it.

### Usage of `@Transactional`

The reasons behind using a topmost `@Transactional` might be multiple, and I guess the developer who wrote this piece of code should be the one answering here.

Still, I can see two main reasons one would do so:

- a poor understanding of `@Transactional` annotation (see rest of the answer),
- pure laziness: the developer did not want to annotate all underlying methods *and* was aware of the risks.

---

According to my experience, this is an extremely risky practice:

I once encountered an issue related to a `@Transactional` on application entrypoint.
The problem was at first not that visible, but showed off when someone added an HTTP call nested in the workflow of that entrypoint.
Indeed, we were opening database connection, doing an HTTP call, writing the response to a database and finally closing the connection.
I let you imagine what happened when the service behind the HTTP call got really slow to answer (for reasons only they know)...
Database connections were basically stacking up without being released on time, leading to saturation of database connection pool.

This would *not* have happened if we simply let the HTTP call being made out of a transaction, since database connections would have been opened *only* when we needed to *actually* access to the database.

> **Personal** conclusion: *always put the `@Transactional` on purely database relative piece of code*. In your example, this would be *at least* on the `EventInterface.groupUpdate` method.

### Using topmost `@Transactional`

Based on the previous answer, I would suggest you place your `@Transactional` on a method which guarantees *by design* that it only relies on your own system.

For your specific issue, I would simply annotate the method persisting the `parentEvent` with an `@Transactional`. With a correct entity relationship graph, your `parentEvent` should only be persisted if all its related entities were, otherwise the persisting event will throw a exception, marking the transaction for rollback (see [`javax.persistence.PersistenceException`](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html)).
If you want to return a decent HTTP status to your client on such events, you might want to either:

- wrap your code in a try/catch to handle the thrown exception
- setup a `RestControllerAdvice` extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` (Spring)

### TLDR;

Make sure your `@Transactional` method relies *by design* only on your system so that your database connection pool is not dependent of another system.